# Combinations in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Using SQL Server (2008) and given a table with rows as follows:

```
Id
--
4
7
```

Using a value for x (e.g. a parameter @x), I want to be able to generate rows with x columns giving the all combinations of the Id values in the table:

For example with x=2, would produce an output with two columns as follows:

```
4,4
4,7
7,4
7,7
```

In this case where x=3, the result would be a rows with three columns as following:

```
4,4,4
4,4,7
4,7,4
4,7,7
7,4,4
7,4,7
7,7,4
7,7,7
```

The table may contain more or less rows than the 2 rows in the above example, which also depending on the value of x would change the number of combination rows/columns in the output.

E.g.
If the table contained:

```
4
7
9
```

If x=2, would produce

```
4,4
4,7
4,9
7,4
7,7
7,9
9,4
9,7
9,9
```

If x=3, would produce

```
4,4,4
4,4,7
4,4,9
4,7,4
4,7,7
4,7,9
4,9,4
4,9,7
4,9,9
etc
```

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? You would have to use dynamic SQL for this.

Comment: Use cross join to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select convert(varchar(max), id) as ids, 1 as cnt
      from t
      union all
      select ids + ',' + convert(varchar(max), id), cnt + 1
      from cte join
           t
           on cte.cnt < @x
     )
select *
from cte
where cnt = @x;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=f7100ea60c4dffe71ce7e29e99058524) is a db<>fiddle.

Note:  you need to represent the results as a string, because SQL does not allow you to return a variable number of columns.  You could put each value in a separate column, but then you would not be able to use a variable to control the size of the combinations.

Answer (score 1):

Another possible approach is to use dynamic SQL:

```
-- Table
CREATE TABLE #Numbers (
   Id int
)
INSERT INTO #Numbers
   (Id)
VALUES
   (4),
   (7),
   (9)

-- Declarations
DECLARE @select nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @from nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @stm nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @x int

-- Numbers
SELECT @x = 2

-- Statement generation 
;WITH CounterCTE as (
   SELECT 1 AS Counter
   UNION ALL
   SELECT Counter + 1   
   FROM CounterCTE
   WHERE Counter < @x
)
SELECT 
   @select = (SELECT CONCAT(N',t', Counter, N'.Id') FROM CounterCTE FOR XML PATH('')),
   @from = (SELECT CONCAT(N',#Numbers t', Counter) FROM CounterCTE FOR XML PATH(''))
SET @stm = CONCAT(
   N'SELECT ', 
   STUFF(@select, 1, 1, N''),
   N' FROM ',
   STUFF(@from, 1, 1, N'')
)   

-- Execution
PRINT @stm
EXEC sp_executesql @stm
```

Output for @x = 2

```
Id  Id
4   4
7   4
9   4
4   7
7   7
9   7
4   9
7   9
9   9
```